# Check to see if an element is visible on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a new problem with a menu that i am making. I am trying to make it hide when the user clicks outside of the menu itself. I can't check the display value of the element, as it is always visible but translated to the right of the element, thus not being in the visible DOM.

The problem is that the button in itself is not working and that the menu is activating when clicking on the screen, so my attempt at making a verification whether the div is visible or not isn't working.I have also tried to use a function with `getBoundingClientRect();` that a lot of people are suggesting, but i stuck around with `document.body.contains(MyElement)`.
This is my JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(x) {
        x.classList.toggle("change");
        document.getElementById("dropdown-meniu-content").classList.toggle("show");}
 $(document).click(function(event) { 
    if ( document.body.contains(document.getElementById('dropdown-meniu-content') ) ) {
        if(!$(event.target).closest('#dropdown-meniu-content').length) {
        document.getElementById("dropdown-meniu-content").classList.toggle("show");
                    document.getElementById("buton-meniu").classList.toggle("change");
        }        
}
```

});
The CSS is :

```
    .logo {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .meniu {
            float: right;
            width: auto;
        }
        .buton-meniu {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 35px;
            margin-right: 30px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .change .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }
        .change .bar2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .change .bar3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        }
        .dropdown-meniu {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown-meniu-content {

            top: 110px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #d6d6d6;
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 10000px;
            height: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        }
        .show {
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="meniu">
        <div class="dropdown-meniu">
            <div id="buton-meniu" class="buton-meniu" onclick="myFunction(this)">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown-meniu-content" class="dropdown-meniu-content">
                <div class="dropdown-ferestre">
                    <div id="buton-ferestre" class="buton-ferestre">Ferestre</div>
                    <div id="dropdown-ferestre-content" class="dropdown-ferestre-content">
                        <p id="demo"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you don't want to look through the code, the JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/1qrtb424/18/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: So you want to show menu on click of `button-meniu` only and hide menu with click anywhere in the document?

Comment: well, i'd like to hide it with a the button and by clicking outside the menu itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking to see if an element is visible on the screen is a hard problem to solve, but I don't think you need to solve it to accomplish your task. There may be some reason you need to do it that way, but, if there isn't, rather than checking whether an element is visible on the screen, you could just check for the presence of the class that makes that element visible.

I meant to rework your javascript less, but it took me a bit to remember the solution to the propagation issue (clicking a button also, by default, counts as a click on the document, unless you add `event.stopPropagation`), and it was easier for me to rewrite. The same principles could be applied in your solution, though.

That's a very nice burger-bar/x button transition, by the way.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#buton-meniu');
var content = document.querySelector('#dropdown-meniu-content');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('change');
  content.classList.toggle('show');
}, true)

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (content.classList.contains('show')) {
    content.classList.remove('show');
    button.classList.remove('change');
  }
})

content.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

```css
.logo {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .meniu {
            float: right;
            width: auto;
        }
        .buton-meniu {
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 35px;
            margin-right: 30px;
            margin-top: 40px;
        }
        .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 6px 0;
            transition: 0.4s;
        }
        .change .bar1 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
            transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
        }
        .change .bar2 {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .change .bar3 {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
            transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
        }
        .dropdown-meniu {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .dropdown-meniu-content {

            top: 110px;
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #d6d6d6;
            width: 30%;
            max-width: 10000px;
            height: 100%;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            right: 0;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease;
        }
        .show {
            transform: translateX(0%);
        }
```

```html
<div class="meniu">
        <div class="dropdown-meniu">
            <div id="buton-meniu" class="buton-meniu" >
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="dropdown-meniu-content" class="dropdown-meniu-content">
                <div class="dropdown-ferestre">
                    <div id="buton-ferestre" class="buton-ferestre">Ferestre</div>
                    <div id="dropdown-ferestre-content" class="dropdown-ferestre-content">
                        <p id="demo"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: your solution is working as intended and i don't have any ulterior motives to checking if my menu is visible. i thought that would be the best way to going around the problem. could you pinpoint me to a link or a tutorial regarding propagation events? I am a noob at javascript and i really want to learn it (i already know some C++ and PHP). thanks again!

Comment: I wish I had a go-to to send you to. MDN is always my first reference, though usually more for docs than tutorials, but they have one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events. FreeCodeCamp is usually pretty good, and they have an explainer as well: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-simplified-explanation-of-event-propagation-in-javascript-f9de7961a06e

Comment: would W3Schools be good enough? I learned CSS, HTML and some of PHP from them and it seems like a good site, but people are saying it is outdated and such

Comment: When I was first learning, someone pointed me to MDN over W3Schools, so I'm more comfortable with it, but, since I almost always go to MDN first, I haven't used W3Schools much and can't actually speak to whether there's a substantial difference. I do think the MDN site looks nicer, which should count for something since the subject matter is front end development.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I will use both sources to learn and ,of course, stack overflow when i get stuck somewere.